# Server on nginx with passenger

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

When run rails app i have error:
`/bin/sh: 1: exec: /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby: Permission denied`

server runing on nginx with passenger

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like, you have installed rvm / gems from the root level, what is *not recommended* from the obvious reasons ( all process which try to reach this directory will need to be run by root as well )

> Single-User installations - For an isolated install within a user's $HOME, 
>   not for root.
>   ( source: https://rvm.io/rvm/install )

try to reinstall yours rvm